# How would I find the sum of the combination of a set of numbers that's closer to a target number, even if it means keeping numbers out of the set?

Tags: algorithm

I'm writing a program for a project that I'm working on, and I need to find the sum of the combination of a set of numbers that's closer to a target. For example, I have the array n = [3,4,2,1,5] and the target is 7, what would be the combination that includes the most numbers out of the array and gets me the closest to 7?

I tried everything and nothing seems to work.

Comment: "I tried everything and nothing seems to work." isn't helpful. Please share the attempt(s) so we can help you with them. By "closer" do you mean closest but possibly exceeding or closest but not exceeding?

Answer (score 0):

You can always try brute forcing it, i.e. trying all possible combinations. But that would be computationally expensive and because the problems has a complexity of N^2, it will basically not work for large inputs.

The problem sounds similar to the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) which is solved very nicely with [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). The idea is to build up your result from the previous results. I think the same approach can be used for your problem as with the coin problem just with some small modifications.